# Get accurate element height

Tags: jquery

I am having difficulty getting correct height of  elements. When I do it  with jQuery:

```
$(this).find(".item:first").height();
```

I get 14, but in reality it is 18px.

I am trying to place the items inside another div and add an overflow. My thought was to get one item's height then multiply by number of items that want to show. By getting a wrong reading I can't seem to be able to accomplish this properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Is it possible to count the height of the group of items, say 1-5 if they all have the same class and are identical?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Comment: Nice, four answers at almost exactly the same time :D, Slaks was fastest though. Nice job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You (probably) are looking for [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/):

```
$(this).find(".item:first").outerHeight(true);
```

The `true` accounts for margins.

Answer (score 2):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're looking for [`.outerHeight(true/false)`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/).

Answer (score 2):

Try `outerHeight()`. Using just `height()` does not take into consideration the margin and padding of the element.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) which optionally (by passing `true`) includes the margin in it's calculation.

Answer (score 1):

the native `offsetHeight` property will give you the actual height of the element including border and padding. http://jsfiddle.net/AY6DV/